# Sum data by today, month, and year

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, sum

I would like sum data by today, month and year. Already using group by but didn't work

my Controller code:

```
$total_steamer = $this->dynamic_model->read('sys_material', 0, 0, 'material_status != 5', false, false, 'SUM(A.material_piece_qty_printed) val ')->row();

$ts =  $total_steamer->val;

$this->view['data'] += 'ts' => $ts;
```

any idea?

I want this **Output**:

```
steam today: 10

steam this month: 20

steam this year: 50
```

Comment: What is your expected output?  I don't see any evidence of aggregation in your code.

Comment: Which DBMS are you working on?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen already update in my question. thx

Comment: @SQL_M im using mysql

Comment: We guessed MySQL, but you never even showed us what output you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen pls check my question, i already update it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by using this query fetch sum of " month, a year " num_calls

```
SELECT MONTH(`date`) AS m, YEAR(`date`) AS y, COUNT(`id`) as count FROM table GROUP BY m, y
```